# How to hide/disable dropdown options until the page has loaded

Tags: html, css

When you refresh the page, all the drop-down options display which does not look good. After the page has completed loading, only one drop-down displays which is the desired behavior.

This is my dropdown code:

Unfortunately, I couldn't get this to work.

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $("#dropdown").prop("disabled", false);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<select id="dropdown" class="special-search-select-box search-translation-select translation-select-default form-control disabled" name="category_name">
  <option value="good-news-translation-gnt">Good News Translation (GNT)</option>
  <option value="king-james-version-kjv" selected="selected">King James Version (KJV)</option>
  <option value="new-international-version-niv">New International Version (NIV)</option>
  <option value="new-king-james-version-nkjv">New King James Version (NKJV)</option>
  <option value="revised-standard-version-rsv">Revised Standard Version (RSV)</option>
</select>
```

[image]

[image]

Comment: I made you a snippet. Please add the CSS and other framework code to make this a "dropdown" and not just a "select" - we need to see a [mcve] - you likely want some .hide()/.show() action

Comment: Shouldn't the `<select>` be disabled in the HTML code, if you want to only enable it after the page loads?

Comment: Yes, I added the disabled attribute but when I reload surprisingly the entire list still shows.

Comment: @Maryongubo PLEASE add the framework code  - bootstrap or whatever it is you are using to style the dropdown. We cannot guess what code the framework produces. They normally replace the HTML with completely other HTML

Comment: This is what I have in my header `<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.4.1/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>` `<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.4.1/css/bootstrap.min.css">`